# Convert a datetime from GMT to other (Eastern, Mountain, Pacific, Indian,..) formats

Tags: c#, datetime

I need to know how to convert a date time of GMT time zone format into other formats like Eastern, Pacific, Mountain and India time zone formats in C#, asp.net 2.0 and dot net framework 2.0.

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108644/c-making-sure-datetime-now-returns-a-gmt-1-time/1108670#1108670

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, you want .NET 3.5 for this...

(I know you asked about .NET 2.0, but this answer may be heplful for somebody searching for this topic in the future)

```
TimeZoneInfo mountain = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(
    "US Mountain Standard Time");
DateTime utc = DateTime.UtcNow;
DateTime local = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utc, mountain);
```

Before then... pain. You can maintain your own list of offsets, but then you have to worry about DST.

Answer (score 2):

Using .NET 2.0 you're mostly stuffed, unfortunately. You'll need to use P/Invoke to create an instance of the [`TimeZone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.aspx) class. From .NET 3.5 onwards it's a lot better - [`TimeZoneInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx) allows you to fetch non-local zones. I seem to remember that the latter has better support for historical time zone information too, instead of just a pair of rules for when DST changes.

You can get information using [GetTimeZoneInformation](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.GetTimeZoneInformation) but that's relatively ugly. There may well be some way of using P/Invoke just to make the conversion for you... although it's still likely to be hairy.

How firm is the requirement to use .NET 2.0? You'd save yourself a *lot* of hassle using .NET 3.5...

Answer (score 0):

Write a method like below, so can easily converted by calling it.
Its for indian standard time

```
public DateTime IndianStandard(DateTime currentDate)
{
    TimeZoneInfo mountain = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");
    DateTime utc = currentDate;
    return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utc, mountain);
}
```