# Why DateTime.Now and DateTime.UtcNow Isn't My Current Local DateTime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, datetime

We use `DateTime.Now`, but the time is not equal with our server time!

When I run my project, these are the `DateTime` property values:

```
DateTime.Now = {15/14/04 05:20:18 AM}
DateTime.UtcNow = {15/14/04 12:20:18 PM}
```

But my current local system time is:

```
15/14/04 04:50:18 AM
```

My time zone is Tehran (UTC+03:30).

This is the first time I've see this behavior! Why doesn't `DateTime.Now` equal my computer's time?

[image]

Comment: Unless you're lucky enough to be on the Prime Meridian, UTCNow will never equal your local timezone.

Comment: What timezone is your server in such that 15/14/04 05:38:56 AM local  is 15/14/04 12:39:15 PM UTC? One with an offset of 7hours and 19seconds?

Comment: Make sure your culture settings are correct - check `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`.

Comment: My Time zone is (UTC+03:30) Tehran.

Comment: Wait - is you date format really `yy/dd/MM`!?

Comment: @user When in doubt, reboot the computer. (not kidding)

Comment: Yes Kobi it is my date format ! i have not any problem with my Date . my problem is in Time !

Comment: Please check Date & Time setting of your windows in control panel and UTC setting.

Comment: xanatos are you kidding me !!! I'm crying because of this problem now :((((

Comment: Is this just happening on your development machine?

Comment: Did you have a daylight saving time change recently? If so, did your computer time change automatically or did you manually change it?

Comment: Are you using remote debugging? What framework version do you use?

Comment: Rashed DIP i check it before sending this comment . not problem . it set on (UTC+03:30) Tehran . and time on my computer is correct .

Comment: Ryan Dansie no it happened on server and my PC (my PC is Developer PC)

Comment: Luaan whaqt is this ? Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture ? how it check in VS ?

Comment: CodeCaster my FrameWork is dotnet 2 and i use project directly in my PC

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure you are not manipulating the timezone somewhere in code, or playing with System.Globalization.CultureInfo
Try to search in all your source code for System.Globalization.CultureInfo may be it is somewhere, also may be the time zone is cached somewhere so try to call  `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData()` before `DateTime.Now`

[.NET DateTime.Now returns incorrect time when time zone is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296918/net-datetime-now-returns-incorrect-time-when-time-zone-is-changed)

Comment: Again, as I wrote in another comment: Culture and time zones are not related so fiddling with `CultureInfo` does not fix time zone issues.

Comment: thanks my  friend . i put 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData() ' befor datetime.now and my problem has been resoled :) So thansks

Comment: I stand corrected. Even though culture and time zones are not related there is a link as can be seen in the [source code for `CultureInfo.ClearCachedData`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/cultureinfo.cs,1373): at line 1373 there is a call to `TimeZone.ResetTimeZone()` so resetting the current culture **also** reset the curent time zone information.

Comment: your link is so amazing ! so you said isn't it a good solution ?

Answer (score 5):

Your timezone is UTC +03:30, but because of daylight saving it's +4:30. This means that when `DateTime.UtcNow = {15/14/04 12:20:18 PM}`, it's `04:50:18 AM` in your timezone, which your clock confirms.

So your `DateTime.Now` doesn't confirm to your machine's datetime settings, making it return a value that doesn't match your clock.

As of why the accepted answer works can be explained by `DateTime.Now` using the `TimeZoneInfo` class to calculate the local time from UTC (using timezone and daylight saving), but I don't know *why* that can run out of sync. Do you never recycle your application pools and never shutdown your machine? ;)

`System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData()` works because it calls `TimeZone.ResetTimeZone()` and `TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData()`.

Comment: Culture is not related to time zones. Culture determines how to format date, time and numbers based on culture. Time zones determine the time based on your location on the earth and the same time zone can have many different cultures and vice versa.

Comment: @Martin you're totally right. What do you suggest, apart from removing this answer? I've found [DateTime.Now and Culture/Timezone specific](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776093/datetime-now-and-culture-timezone-specific) and [C#: Making sure DateTime.Now returns a GMT + 1 time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108644/c-making-sure-datetime-now-returns-a-gmt-1-time) which seem relevant, but no pointers as to the cause of "DateTime.Now not corresponding to machine settings".

Comment: I have no good answer to the question. Perhaps there is some something we do not know but that is very important in understanding the question but the deluge of comments to the questions I do not think I have anything to add.

Comment: thanks friends for your help . i ran the first answer and it worked :)